# How do i make a class that MUST be instantiated

Tags: c#

how do I make a class that MUST be instantiated it, or anything like that. If it is possible anyway..

Comment: a static class cannot be instatiated. If you want to force a class to be instantiated, just make a normal class with only instance methods defined on it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I get the feeling you want to limit this class to only one instance. If that's the case, look into the singleton pattern.

Comment: @sstan yeah i know that a static class cannot be instantiated did you even read the title and the description? please dont take this as offensive

Comment: As others have pointed out, a static class cannot be instantiated, so the question as stated is impossible to answer. Is it possible to share a little more information on what you are trying to achieve? What would be a typical use case or scenario? Is there a particular usage pattern you are trying to enforce or prevent that is not already covered by non-static classes?

Comment: @CarstenHansen im trying to make a class that MUST be instantiated well... im gonna have to edit this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make a class with no static members, you know. You must instantiate a class with no static members in order to use its functionalities. Although it still inherits from `Object`'s static members. But if you want to remove that as well, I am sorry but it is impossible.

Comment: Thanks just the answer i wanted lol your pretty early too and that the solution was so easy :/